# run out of memory by repeatedly exporting worksheets using VBA in 64-bit Excel

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I need to export processed data from a master file to a large number of ".xlsx" ouput files.
In the master file, I run VBA code to repeat the following:
1). insert a new worksheet.
2). put processed output data in that newly inserted worksheet.
3). move the worksheet to a new workbook and save that workbook.

After a little over 2400 worksheets have been exported this way, Excel displays an error message, mentioning that "there isn't enough memory to complete this action", and suggesting the use of 64-bit Excel.

I changed to 64-bit Excel. The same message appeared after more or less the same number of output files had been produced.

Since 64-bit software allows a much larger memory space, if the 64-bit version and the 32-bit version exhaust memory at the same point of progress, it seems to me that the problem might not have been caused by normal memory usage.

May be it is caused by something like calling fopen() repeatedly without calling fclose() in C.

The skeleton of my code is like:

```
Cur_Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False             
For r = 12 To 4653   

      ' Add Blank sheet
      Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))          

      ' Export Sheet
      Export_fname = Cur_Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
      ws.Move
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Export_fname, FileFormat _
          :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
      ActiveWindow.Close

Next r    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The debugger showed that the problem arose when running the line "ws.Move".

Would anyone please let me know what is wrong with my code, or suggest a work-around to get over that (seemingly) 2433 worksheets limit?

Comment: By chance, are you using any  objects elsewhere in the code?  ...and perhaps an instance of Excel?  Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and also see **how to create a [mcve]**.

Comment: If you have this much data, you might want to look into a database solution, 2433+ worksheets would be a bit unwieldy to work with.

Comment: You could create the worksheet in the new workbook.  I think the problem you're having is available memory - each sheet is retained in your original workbook and number of sheets allowed is limited by available memory.   [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Thank you Darren for your kind suggestion. I've tried getting the work done in a Create_workbook - write_data_to_it - Close_workbook cycle. The "there isn't enough memory" message appeared after the 2426th output file has been produced. The debugger showed that the problem arose when running the function "Workbooks.Add" for creating the 2427th output file.

Comment: Sorry Darren, my mistake. Your code works. The problem is solved. It's my adaption of your code which has failed at the 2427th output file. I will check my code and fix it.
Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: Are the formats of the files you are importing the same? Maybe append them to 1 sheet with an identifier in an column instead of creating a new sheet each time would be a better approach, if the formats are the same. Also, using ADODB to open the Excel files instead of with the Excel Object model might be faster too.

Answer (score 0):

This may work better - each workbook only has 1 sheet and none are stored in the original book.
You haven't said how you put the processed data on the sheet so I've just populated a few cells with data.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim Cur_Path As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Cur_Path = ThisWorkbook.Path

    For r = 12 To 4653
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'Create workbook with 1 sheet.
        Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets(1) 'Set reference to worksheet.
        With wrkSht
            .Name = wrkSht.Name & " - " & r 'Ensure a unique name.
            'Populate the sheet with some data.
            .Range("A1") = wrkSht.Name
            .Range("B1:D1") = Array(ThisWorkbook.Name, wrkBk.Name, Cur_Path)
        End With
        wrkBk.SaveAs Filename:=Cur_Path & "\" & wrkSht.Name & ".xlsx", _
                     FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wrkBk.Close
    Next r

End Sub
```